# Minicom doesn't take keyboard input

Tags: minicom

I am trying to work with the TI TMDSLCDK138 development board. I have installed the SDK in Ubuntu 18.04.6 and developed a boot file and the board is connected to the PC using a USB-UART connector. While the board is powered on I have configured minicom version 2.7.1 for serial communication, and I am able to see the boot-up configuration, but I am not able to provide the keyboard input to the development board.

I have searched this and come across one solution like installing gtkterm and using it, thus I have installed gtkterm and port settings are done as per requirement. I am able to write to the development board using gtkterm, but gtkterm not correctly it hangs, so I tried to open the minicom simultaneously with the same port configuration. Now through minicom also a keyboard can be provided, but if I close gtkterm it is not working.

It is irregularly working. I have attached a screenshot containing minicom and gtkterm. In minicom some characters are not visible, but the command executes correctly.

The command provided is `uname -r` :

[image: incorrect data in minicom]

How to rectify this?